# Colorama, Fore is applying red to the whole code

Tags: python, import, colorama

So I have imported the module Colorama and used `print(Fore.RED + "JasoPC copyright 2022")` and it applies this to every print and text displayed under it, how do I fix this?

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore

user = input("Please enter your name_>>> ")
print(Fore.RED + "JasoPC copyright 2022")
print("Current Version V.1.3.6")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("BOOTING UP 0%")
time.sleep(1)
print("BOOTING UP 25%")
time.sleep(1)
print("BOOTING UP 75%")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("BOOTING UP 100%")
print("ALL DONE")
time.sleep(0.3)
print("configuring[...]")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add  Fore.RESET

```py
print(Fore.RED + "JasoPC copyright 2022" + Fore.RESET)
```

Comment: Do you know of any place that contains all the Fore colors?, and it is accurate?

Comment: Here the [link](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/blob/master/colorama/ansi.py#L49-68)

Comment: What does the = # mean?